# How to access 2 google-drives on one computer?

Tags: google-drive

I've got google drive for work and google drive for personal.  How can I access both of them at the same time and also make sure that the sync feature works for both.

Answer (score 1):

Login to google drive.

Select a folder(s) and select share.  Enter the email address of the account your not logged into.  Now all the contents will show up in that account with whatever permissions you give yourself.

No sync required.

Once shared you can transfer files back and forth inside google drive.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but supposedly this software works:  [Insync](https://www.insynchq.com/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but for those who are looking for a solution today:

- Select 'Add New Account' from the backup & sync menu
- Use your 2th Google Account to login
- This will install a 2th instance of backup & sync

Both work completely independent from each other.